# Unique token for each user in ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, token, asp.net-identity

So far as I understand, the token from ASP NET Identity is can be use for another user within same Role. So, I still using another value like username/password for authenticate the action from user that have a token.

I am new on ASP NET Identity, so can we built unique token from each user?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So far as I understand, the token from ASP NET Identity is can be use
>   for another user within same Role.

This is not correct. One token must only be used for a unique user. Tokens are not shared between users! 
However, a user can create several different tokens.

> So, I still using another value like username/password for
>   authenticate the action from user that have a token.

As I said, a token is unique for one user, so you only need a token to identify a user and the actions that can be accesses. In fact, the token string has information of Roles and Claims of the user.

Comment: Oh, maybe I missed something. Is there any different using ASP NET Identity in Web API development? I have used it. Is there something wrong in purpose?

Comment: It shouldn't be different. Check this link to see the complete process and implementation: http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

Comment: Maybe I've been mistaken in API development. Is it true that if I conclude when we have received the token, it is same as we have been logged in?

Comment: Yes, if you have a token you are logged in. Of course if the token is not expired. That's why it's better to check that the user is authenticated using "RequestContext.Principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated" property. Check this link (from the same author of the other link) to get new token when it expires using Refresh tokens: http://bitoftech.net/2014/07/16/enable-oauth-refresh-tokens-angularjs-app-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin/  ... Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, thanks for explanation and the links. So far, I'm only using [Authorize] attribute (include Roles) for authentication.